# Trying to stop altering symbols in URLs

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, urls

I am trying to create a bibliography and my main source of information are websites. The problem I'm having is when copying the URL into the bibliography, LaTeX doesn't like typesetting all the symbols. I have tried simply going through each URL and changing each symbol to be shown correctly but it is taking up far too much time. Is there a way to enclose the URL in speech marks for instance and have it just show the URL without me having to alter each symbol. Something like raw text or creating a string?

```
\bibitem{wikisocialnetwork01}
Social network,
Wikipedia contributors,
Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia,
Date of last revision: 6 March 2012,
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Social_network&oldid=480326647
```

Comment: Have you tried the [url package](http://www.stack.nl/~jwk/latex/examples/node4.html)?

Comment: Thanks I used that and it worked properly. Also from that able to have them as clickable links. Thanks.

For anyone else with this problem follow this link. http://www.stack.nl/~jwk/latex/examples/node4.html

Comment: Cool, I turned my comment into an [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47000/4797).

Comment: Although this may be personal preference, you should consider registering the same account across the StackExchange network. In order to achieve this, register with the same OpenID, or request that moderators merge accounts registered under different OpenIDs. See [Suggestions for account merging across StackExchange network](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2343/5764) for more information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`url` package](http://www.stack.nl/~jwk/latex/examples/node4.html), which will take care of all this automatically.